# SQL help required

Tags: sql

I have a question which asks:

> Make a list of all data stored in da_students, da_enrolments and da_courses. Write a query that makes all columns appear only once in the output, the rows are sorted by students' first name ascending AND course_id descending so that students are grouped by course (without using a group by clause) and generated first/ last names( fname.., Lname...) do not appear in the output.

The current code I have is:

```
SELECT *
FROM DA_STUDENTS
    FULL JOIN DA_ENROLMENTS ON student_id = student_student_id 
    FULL JOIN DA_COURSES ON course_course_id = course_id
ORDER BY first_name ASC, course_id DESC;
```

Any help please?

Comment: What is the problem with your query?

Comment: Odd column names... Use same name if possible, use table aliases etc e.g. FROM DA_STUDENTS s FULL JOIN DA_ENROLMENTS e ON s.student_id = e.student_id

Comment: I tried that but still didn't work! :/

Comment: Jens, it's not combining the columns and I cannot remove the fname and lname data!

Comment: Even thought the asterix * is usefull for quickly testing a query, it is generally considered bad practice. Just list the names of the columns that you want the query to return (the aliases jarlh mentioned can help you with this) so you could start with something like 
SELECT s.[first_name], c.[course_id]

Comment: IT WORKED!! Now I just need to get rid of the fname and lname test data..

Comment: I have this code thus far:

SELECT s.student_id, first_name, last_name, course_id, course_title, start_date, end_date FROM DA_STUDENTS s INNER JOIN DA_ENROLMENTS e
ON s.student_id = e.student_student_id 
INNER JOIN DA_COURSES c ON e.course_course_id = c.course_id
ORDER BY first_name ASC, course_id DESC;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start with: The sorting thing is not well explained. It even looks like it is indented to obfuscate. To sort by student name and course but have the students grouped by course in the end, simply means order by course and then by student.

Then: "generated first/last names ... do not appear in the output". What? How are they generated? Aren't they simple columns in the students table? As to showing something in the output or not: state what you want to show in your SELECT clause. Other columns will not be shown of course.

As to "Make a list of all data stored in da_students, da_enrolments and da_courses": This means all students, all courses plus the associtated enrolements:

```
from da_students s
cross join da_courses c
left join da_enrolments e on e.student_id = s.student_id and e.course_id = c.course_id
```

As to "Write a query that makes all columns appear only once in the output": This means, don't

```
select *
```

nor

```
select s.student_id, e.student_id, ...
```

but only

```
select s.student_id, ...
```

so as to show the student ID only once.